# Symfony3 Form Type and ManyToMany relation

Tags: symfony

How to configure form type with many to many relation?

Below configuration...

Form/Type/ProductType.php

```
$builder
    ->add('name')
    ->add('price')
    ->add('description', TextareaType::class)
    ->add('quantity')
    ->add('shopProductImages', EntityType::class, [
        'class'        => 'AppBundle:ShopProductImages',
        'choice_label'=>'file',
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repo) {
            return $repo->createQueryBuilder('f')
                ->where('f.id > :id')
                ->setParameter('id', 1);
        },

    ])

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => ShopProducts::class,
    ]);
}
```

Entity/ShopProducts.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="shop_products")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ShopProducts
{
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\ShopProductImages", mappedBy="shopProducts")
     */
    private $shopProductImages;
```

Entity/ShopProductImages.php

```
 * @ORM\Table(name="shop_product_images")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ShopProductImages
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="file", type="text", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $file;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_mod", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $dateMod;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\ShopProducts", inversedBy="shopProductImages")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="shop_product_images_has_shop_products",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="shop_product_images_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="shop_products_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $shopProducts;
```

...ends with error
[image]

Comment: could you please give some more details what you try to do?
also try to use " 'class'        => ShopProductImages:class" in your form

Comment: Can you give the complete entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `ManyToMany` has more than 1 option:

- [ManyToMany-Unidirectional](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional)
- [ManyToMany-Bidirectional](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional)

so you need to deternmine which is your case? is it uni/bi directional and use the correct approach over there

also you may consider the really good advice from doctrine:

> Why are many-to-many associations less common? Because frequently you
>   want to associate additional attributes with an association, in which
>   case you introduce an association class. Consequently, the direct
>   many-to-many association disappears and is replaced by
>   one-to-many/many-to-one associations between the 3 participating
>   classes.

and as for your error some pieces of code are missing, but the error explains it self: you have a file object which is waiting for a path -should be a string- and you are giving it an object -probably you are passing the whole file- look in your `ShopController` to see where the file attribute is being set and there you can debug the error and without seeing the code i guess it'll be something like this

```
setFile($fileObject)
```

you need to change to

```
setFile($fileObject->getPath());
```

otherwise i need to see the code in order to fix it.